# Android Application Suspend Resume

Tags: android

My android application has multiple Activities. I need to perform a few things when the Application resumes (Application not Activity).

Android application provides onCreate callback but no onResume callback.
Is there any way I can identify that my application has resumed?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am having the same question with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Activities do have onResume()  see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

// ...

}
```

So when your application resumes - one of your activities will resume - handle it in each activity.

Comment: he is asking for application onresume not for activity

Comment: true - so he should handle it in each activity.

Comment: But how do I differentiate if the resume is due to another application and not due to my own Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Applications do not get paused or resumed, only individual activities do. You can think of the `Application` class as of a static object that gets created before any of your activities (that's why it has a `onCreate()` function) and gets destroyed when the system kills the process (no `onDestroy()` involved here).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way you can do that is through the Activity.  If you're looking to call something across all your Activities in the onResume you can probably use a static singleton as is suggested in the Application docs:

> There is normally no need to subclass
>   Application. In most situation, static
>   singletons can provide the same
>   functionality in a more modular way.
>   If your singleton needs a global
>   context (for example to register
>   broadcast receivers), the function to
>   retrieve it can be given a Context
>   which internally uses
>   Context.getApplicationContext() when
>   first constructing the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Use ProcessLifecycleOwner [ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner) .

It will dispatch Lifecycle.Event.ON_START, Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME events, as a first activity moves through these events.

And Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE, Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP, events will be dispatched with a delay after a last activity passed through them